# In Outlook 2010, what is the purpose size ranges in an email message list

Tags: email

In Outlook 2010, one of my students has asked why her incoming emails are grouped by size such as `med 25 -100kb` and `small 10-25Kb` following incoming emails.

It does not seem specific. I am not familiar with 2010 and can't answer her questions. Help!

Comment: You need to be more specific. Where does it say what? Maybe an example.

Comment: The size of an email will be based on the contents of the email itself. If you clarify your question I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Negated the downvote as it appears @Ramhound barely read the question.

Answer (score 1):

She has sorted them by size, people can do this in order to get rid of the biggest mails and thus free some space in their inbox. This dates back from the days inbox space was limited...